# Is there a genealogy test for pets?

Tags: genetics

Is there a test out there like "23 and me" except for pets? Is there even anything out there like this? I would pay top-dollar to have this done. I'd like to see if my cat has any Cheeta in her.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of them. Here are 3 in no particular order:

- [catdnatest.org](http://www.catdnatest.org/)
- [Veterinary Genetics Laboratory at the University of California](https://www.vgl.ucdavis.edu/services/cat/ancestry/index.php)
- [Basepaws](https://www.basepaws.com/)

You're looking at $100 and more.

These tests have been around a while. Here's an article from Wired magazine in 2012: [New Genetic Test Reveals Your Cat's Ancestry](https://www.wired.com/2012/07/cat-ancestry-test/) and this blog post by Cherise Udell from 2013: [Learn your Cat's Ancestry](http://www.care2.com/greenliving/learn-your-cats-ancestry.html).

There are also many companies that check pet DNA for specific diseases, with PKD being the most important one for cats.

There are other pets and animals that can be tested as well, e.g. [Embark](https://embarkvet.com/) or [DNA My Dog](http://dnamydog.com/) for dogs, but also companies that do horses especially for horseracing pedigrees, cattle, swine, goats, llamas, etc. for animal breeding purposes.

I have never used any of them, so caveat emptor.